# Rendering ReactJS with CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm brand new to React and am for some reason having trouble getting it to properly render a piece of CSS.

I have a react class, App that should display a Card that has on it a progress tracker.

```
var App = React.createClass({
render: function () {
    var pushNotifications = _.map(this.props.pushNotifications, function(value, key, notification) {
        return (
            <div className="row" key={1}>
                <div className="col-sm-12">
                    <Card>
                        <h1>Title</h1>
                        <div className="clearfix">
                            <ol class="progtrckr" data-progtrckr-steps="5">
                                <li class="progtrckr-done">Order Processing</li>
                                <li class="progtrckr-done">Pre-Production</li>
                                <li class="progtrckr-done">In Production</li>
                                <li class="progtrckr-done">Shipped</li>
                                <li class="progtrckr-todo">Delivered</li>
                            </ol>
                            <div className="pull-right">
                                <p>Total: {iOSTotal}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </Card>
```

Card is defined as:

```
 module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="card">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>

        )
    }
});
```

And the proctrckr CSS is in the css/build file as:

```
    ol.progtrckr {
  display: table;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%; }

ol.progtrckr li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3em; }

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-done {
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 4px solid yellowgreen; }

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-todo {
  color: silver;
  border-bottom: 4px solid silver; }

ol.progtrckr li:after {
  content: "\00a0\00a0"; }

ol.progtrckr li:before {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -2.5em;
  float: left;
  left: 50%;
  line-height: 1em; }

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-done:before {
  content: "\2713";
  color: white;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  height: 1.2em;
  width: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1.2em; }

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-todo:before {
  content: "\039F";
  color: silver;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  bottom: -1.6em; }
```

But, for some reason, it just appears as a regular ordered list, without any of the CSS I put in.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: If you open the console, you should see an error noting you cannot use `class`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `class` with `className`. Common jsx gotcha. [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html).

> Since JSX is JavaScript, identifiers such as `class` and `for` are
>   discouraged as XML attribute names. Instead, React DOM components
>   expect DOM property names like `className` and `htmlFor`, respectively.

```
<ol className="progtrckr" data-progtrckr-steps="5">
  <li className="progtrckr-done">Order Processing</li>
  <li className="progtrckr-done">Pre-Production</li>
  <li className="progtrckr-done">In Production</li>
  <li className="progtrckr-done">Shipped</li>
  <li className="progtrckr-todo">Delivered</li>
</ol>
```